# Angular-ui Bootstrap Tabs - Is there a way to prevent tab selection?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using Angular-UI Bootstrap tabs and would like to prevent tab selection during the select event handler. I have tried setting the tab.active to false and setting another tab.active to true, but that doesn't appear to work while in the context of the select event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'disabled' instead.
Something similar to:

```
ng-click="tabs.disabled = ! tabs.disabled"
```

that should disable or enable the tab.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was trying to set the status to a primitive scope value when it seems to require an object with a property that holds the boolean value.